# Scheduling a Quartz.net Job with dependency-injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, quartz.net

I'm working on my first project with EF Core, and Dependency Injecion for the DB Context.  However I'm running into an issue because Quartz.net 3 seems to not allow any parameters on the ImportJob Class.  So my method of DI, doesn't work in this instance.  I know I want a new context, because this is going to run in the background, is there a different way to create a DB Context so that I can Execute this task?

```
public class ImportJob : IJob
{
    private readonly SContext _db;

    //Quartz.net doesn't appear to like that I'm injecting these, 
    //because if I remove this parameter, execute...executes.
    public ImportJob(SContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var cc = new CC(_db);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [StdSchedulerFactory](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html), a Job Factory that implements [IJobFactory](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/2.0/html/html/eac63cfb-04e7-4c0b-d577-bc2d77a07826.htm) and takes a [IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Example**

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

   public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
      => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

   public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
   {
      try
      {
         var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
         var jobType = jobDetail.JobType;
         return _serviceProvider.GetService(jobType) as IJob;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

         throw new SchedulerException($"Problem instantiating class '{bundle.JobDetail.JobType.FullName}'", ex);
      }
   }

   public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
      => (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
}
```

Depending on your DI framework the registrations would look a little like this

```
// register, your container as an IServiceProvider
container.RegisterInstance<IServiceProvider>(container);

// create the scheduler
var scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

// add your factory to the scheduler
scheduler.JobFactory = new JobFactory(container);

// register the scheduler
container.RegisterInstance(scheduler);

// register your jobs

container.Collection.Register<IJob>(GetType().Assembly);
```

Then you jobs can look like this

```
public class ImportJob : IJob
{
    private readonly SContext _db;

    //Quartz.net doesn't appear to like that I'm injecting these, 
    //because if I remove this parameter, execute...executes.
    public ImportJob(SContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var cc = new CC(_db);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : This is the basic idea not a complete example, and it will depend a lot on your own setup and framework</sub>

In short, what the above does is when Quartz creates a *job* it uses your Factory and *container* to spin up the job allowing for injection.

Comment: I'm new to DI & EF Core, I don't see where my _db is in your example?

Comment: @JoeStellato This is DI / Quartz issue not a jobs issue. what its doing is allow your jobs to support DI. it does this by using your own job factory and your container to spin up the job and DI